# CSS - Webkit transition not working on input type

Tags: html, css

I have webkit transition in place for my forms where when you click on a textfield, the placeholder disappears using a transition. However the same transition is working on the form [contact](http://www.veebox.io/company/contact) form but not on the [sign up](http://www.veebox.io/accounts/signup) form. The transition used is

```
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 30ms ease-in-out;
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please post here code that can reproduce this error. Also, how does this placeholder transition work?

Comment: `box-shadow` transition has nothing to do with placeholder transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS transition that you posted is irrelevant. The transition has nothing to do with the `box-shadow` property.

You are transitioning the `text-indent` property on one page, but not the other. It looks like you need to style the [`::-webkit-input-placeholder` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3A-webkit-input-placeholder). For more information on the [`::-webkit-input-placeholder` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3A-webkit-input-placeholder), see the MDN documentation.

Therefore, add the following:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    -webkit-transition: text-indent .5s ease,color .5s ease;
    color: #899096;
}
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-indent: 10em;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Some placeholder" />
```

I tested it in my browser and it appears to work as expected in Chrome/Safari.